# Hibernate deleteEntity issues

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, persistence

There are two domain objects (lets call them A and B) which use Hibernate identically for delete/remove.

I'm able to only delete A but not B objects, and there are no exceptions and no logging that report any errors.
Both object types use the same service methods for deletion.

```
public void delete(T instance) {
    getEntityManager().remove(instance);
}
```

I have drilled my way down to where B stops and A is able to go further to successful deletion.
And B stops in class `EntityDeleteAction`; meaning that method `@Override public void execute() throws HibernateException` never gets called for B in `EntityDeleteAction`.

I can't find usage of the execute method, and I have compared states at various stages and can't find any abnormalities there (there might be).

Anyone have experience with Hibernate/[EntityDeleteAction](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/action/internal/EntityDeleteAction.html) and can give me an idea of what the problem can be?

**UPDATE**

I found the cause of why B's won't delete. And that is because A has a reference to a collection of B's.
And this collection loads eagerly instead of lazily. This code illustrates it:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "a", targetEntity = B.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<B> bCollection = new HashSet<B>();
```

Delete will work by changing to `FetchType.LAZY`. But in this application we don't keep hibernate/jpa sessions open, so lazy loading will not work in other parts of the application if it tries to resume loading lazily after session has been closed.
So we found the cause but not a solution since we want to keep eager loading.

Is it a way to detach B from A before deleting? It's the active reference from A to B that is causing issues.

Comment: Try `getEntityManager().refresh(instance)` before calling `remove()`. Also, can you post the code that calls this `delete()` method?

Comment: @PredragMaric  I updated the post with more info. A loads a collections of B's with FetchType.EAGER. By changing to LAZY then deletion will work. But we have issues with using LAZY as well and want to find a way to make it work with EAGER loading. Refresh instance did not work btw.

Comment: Strange, haven't had a problem like this. What if you delete it with HQL? `"delete from B where id = " + b.getId()`

Comment: The query is fine. I posted the solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simply to remove B from the collection in A before deleting from database, thereby removing the reference to B from A which was the problem.

```
collectionOfBObjects.remove(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a flush after the delete call and enable Hibernate SQL logging.

Comment: I have tried flush and refresh, and no luck. I updated my original post.